# Como llamar campos especificos Firebase Database Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Buen dia, Tengo este modelo

```
 private Button verdosis, verhipo;
private String Lista="dosis";
private String lis2="Hipoglucemia";
private TextView textViewf,textViewhipo;
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
FirebaseDatabase databas1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference fReference = database.getReference().child(Lista);
DatabaseReference fReference2 = databas1.getReference().child(lis2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    verdosis =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonverdosis);
    verhipo =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonverhipo);
    textViewf =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewf);
    textViewhipo =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewhipo);


    verdosis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String valor = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    textViewf.setText(valor);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

            }

    });
```

y quiero poder llamar mostrar los datos por que me muestra de esta manera y no quiero no es facil de leer quiero que me muestre despues de los primeros : puntos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, sugiero que no publiques tu código en una imagen.

Comment: Gracias modificare la pregunta

Comment: En principio te diría que no tienes una buena estructura de datos. Eso dificulta la buena lectura de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas abrir un segundo bucle para leer los elementos que habrá en `dosis` y obtener sus valores.

Puedes irlos guardando en un `StringBuilder` y al final sacarlos en el `TextView`:

```
    final StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    fReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot oneDosis : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                sb.append(oneDosis.getValue().toString());
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator") );
            }
            textViewf.setText(sb.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled");
        }
    });
```

En una prueba que hice con una estructura parecida a la tuya, tengo esto en el `TextView`:

```
dosis1
dosis2
```

Si tú sacas por pantalla el contenido de `dataSnapshot`, vas a tener algo como esto:

```
{ key = dosis, value = {1=dosis1, 2=dosis2} }
```

Necesitas por tanto un segundo bucle para iterar sobre esta parte de los datos y obtener sus valores:

```
{1=dosis1, 2=dosis2}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84035/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-llamar-campos-especificos-firebase-databa).

Answer (score 0):

creo que comprendo lo que intentas hacer te lo explicare, para que puedas obtener Hipoglucemia,Fecha y hora por separado, debes guardarlos por separado en el mismo hijo, es decir tienes el hijo push que es lo que te pone firedatabase por defecto dentro de ese hijo pones hipoglucemia y el valor, fecha y el valor, hora y el valor de esta manera lo puedes extraer de una clase modelo y te queda mas fácil, ahora puedes crear un Split  y dejarlo como lo tienes ahí te quedaría algo así

```
String[] cadena = valor.split(" ");
```

y para reclamar los valores o mas bien para obtenerlos te quedara un vector tal de que en la primera posición `cadena[0]`tendrás Hipoglusemia:50  en la segunda posición `cadena[1]`tendrás fecha:25/09/2018 y en la tercera posición `cadena[2]` tendrás la hora.

Lo mismo sucedería para el caso de las dosis.

Te sugiero que lo hagas con una clase modelo ya que es mucho mas ordenado, asi como te lo intente explicar anteriormente, espero haberte ayudado